# Add closing button to open slidetoggle div

Tags: jquery, html, button, toggle, slide

I have this code:

```
$('.open-mypage1').click(function () {
   $('#mypage-info1').slideToggle('2000', "swing", function () {
        // Animation complete.
   });
});   

http://jsfiddle.net/haifisch/q59dz078/4/
```

It works fine, but instead of clicking the "open my page?" button to close the toggled div, I would like to have a seperate "close" button within the opened div.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$('.open-mypage1,#mypage-info1 button').click(toggleDiv);
function toggleDiv(){
 $('#mypage-info1').slideToggle('2000', "swing", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q59dz078/6/)**

Or if you solely want the text to open it and the button to close it, you could use:

```
$('.open-mypage1').click(function(){
    $('#mypage-info1').slideDown('2000', "swing", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
$('#mypage-info1 button').click(function(){
    $('#mypage-info1').slideUp('2000', "swing", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3ra3fdws/)**

Comment: What if I would want to have this function for several divs?

Comment: If you can make a jsFiddle example of the HTML structure with several divs I can better understand what you mean.

Comment: It is part of a portfolio, on click of the items headline i want the content to slide open. i got it running for one portfolio item div (as you can see in the fiddle, headline one works), but I'm clueless on how to change the code to make it work for several portfolio item divs with different content
    http://jsfiddle.net/etdc732p/

Comment: Well this works for multiple headlines: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/etdc732p/1/ but I have a feeling that you want to associate the headlines with a block of text, which your fiddle doesn't seem to show.

Comment: I want the headlines to open different contents, not just one. my example was a bit confusing, sorry for that. i tried building what i thought would be a working code, but its not. the first headline opens, but the second and third doesnt :( http://jsfiddle.net/etdc732p/3/

Comment: YES!! Perfect! Thank you.
One more thing (I hope I'm not a huge pain in the ass, but I'm fairly new to this):
I would like to be able to slide through the toggled divs. When the div from headline one is open, I want it to be possible to slide to the content of headline 2 with a little arrow button. I hope you understand what i mean

Comment: Sorry, that's a different question, and more involved than what the comments here can accommodate.

Comment: Ok. What if I want the only one div open at a time? I have opened one headline, i want to close it immediately when another headline is clicked

Comment: You are a star! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use slideUp and slideDown insetad of the slideToggle. On click to open the content div you will have slideDown or opening the div, and on close you will have the slideUp for closing the content div.

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/q59dz078/5/

```
$('.open-mypage1').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#mypage-info1').stop().slideDown('2000', "swing");
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.close-mypage1').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#mypage-info1').stop().slideUp('2000', "swing");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```